# ./psh.phar docker:ssh is not executing

Tags: docker, shopware

I'm trying to build my first plugin in Shopware 6. I'm trying to execute the following command inside the development folder:

```
./psh.phar docker:ssh
```

I get this message:

```
docker exec -i --env COLUMNS=`tput cols` --env LINES=`tput lines` -u 1000:1000 -t  bash
"docker exec" requires at least 2 arguments.
```

Can somebody please tell me how to fix this error?

Comment: Did you started the container with `./psh.phar docker:start` ?

Answer (score 1):

The reasons is most probably what Christopher already commented, that you did not start the container using `./psh.phar docker:start`

At least I am getting the exact same message, if I did not start the docker containers. After starting the containers, `./psh.phar docker:ssh` works

If we look at the script that ? docker:ssh executes we see, that after the Parameter "-t" the container ID (`__APP_ID__`) would be provided

```
$ cat dev-ops/docker/actions/ssh.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

TTY: docker exec -i --env COLUMNS=`tput cols` --env LINES=`tput lines` -u 
__USERKEY__ -t __APP_ID__ bash
```

In your error message this is blank, so obviously the container is not started.